# Xamarin Forms Default value for Picker

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, picker

I want to get the first data when opening my page but it doesn't. I don't know where I made the mistake. Can someone help?

This my Code;

Xaml

```
<Picker FontSize="15"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject}"
        VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        ItemsSource="{Binding myList}"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Title}">
```

ViewModel

```
public myViewModel()
{
    GetList();
    SelectedObject = myList[0];
}



public myClass _selectedObject;

public myClass SelectedObject
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedObject;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectedObject= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedObject");

    }
}
```

Class

```
public class myClass
{
   public int ID { get; set; }

   public string Title{ get; set; }

   public string Desc{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by getting first data? Let picker select the first row? Or get the value of first row in Picker? Or something others?

Comment: I mean select the first row.

Comment: Hi do you want the first item display on picker without selecting it?Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, I want to exactly that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Picker.SelectedIndex>0</Picker.SelectedIndex>
```

or

```
SelectedIndex="{Binding Index}"
```

or swap your attributes order

```
<Picker FontSize="15"
    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    ItemsSource="{Binding myList}"
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Title}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject}>
```

Comment: If you swap the order of your attributes to make sure `SelectedItem` is the last one, this should (almost certainly) work.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean. I can understand better if you share a sample code.

Comment: Swapping the order of SelectedItem fixed my issue.

Comment: I am still not able to make the default choice work, even though I switched the attribute order as suggested. However, I consider using the Title attribute for the default choice, so that it looks correct in the UI (the correct object is indeed chosen, so the Title is just for UI)

Comment: is `{Binding SelectedObject}` something that is automatic known by the application, or should I declare/create something with this name ? What is this ?

Answer (score 2):

I just write a demo and I made it work, you can check it and find out where you have made a mistake:

In code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        myViewModel vm = new myViewModel();
        this.BindingContext = vm;

        //This will also work
        //myPicker.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}

public class myViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public List<myClass> myList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public myViewModel()
    {
        GetList();
        SelectedObject = myList[0];
    }

    public void GetList() {

        myList = new List<myClass>();

        myList.Add(new myClass(1,"firstTitle","FirstDesc"));
        myList.Add(new myClass(2, "SecondTitle", "SecondDesc"));
        myList.Add(new myClass(3, "ThirdTitle", "ThirdDesc"));

    }

    public myClass _selectedObject;


    public myClass SelectedObject
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedObject;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedObject = value;

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedObject"));
        }
    }
}

public class myClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Desc { get; set; }

    public myClass(int a , string title , string desc) {

        ID = a;
        Title = title;
        Desc = desc;
    }
}
```

And in Xaml:

```
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
<Picker x:Name="myPicker" FontSize="15"
        BackgroundColor="Red"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    ItemsSource="{Binding myList}"
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Title}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject}"
        />
```

I upload my sample [here](https://github.com/XfHua/Picker-MVVM/upload). Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you Jack Hua.  "myPicker.SelectedIndex = 0;" that worked for me.

Comment: @YasinGundogdu Can you accept this answer if it helps you?

Comment: is `{Binding SelectedObject}` something that is automatic known by the application, or should I declare/create something with this name ? What is this ?

Comment: @GuidoG `{Binding SelectedObject}` calls `SelectedObject` which is a property declared in the ViewModel (called `myViewModel` above). `this.BindingContext = new myViewModel();` let the program know that all the properties mentioned in the XAML code of the page can be found inside `myViewModel` 