# Cannot set Picker Default value

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a picker on my Xamarin form, bound to a list, and I would like that it has the first item of that list already selected when the form is opening.

My list looks like this

```
Languages = new List<string>();
Languages.Add("English");
Languages.Add("Nederlands");
Languages.Add("русский");
```

I tried like this

```
<Picker x:Name="PickerLanguage" Title="" 
        TitleColor="#004973" 
        FontSize="24" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}"
        SelectedIndex="0"
        SelectedItem="English">
</Picker>
```

and like this

```
<Picker x:Name="PickerLanguage" Title="" 
        TitleColor="#004973" 
        FontSize="24" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}"
        SelectedIndex="0"
        SelectedItem="0">
</Picker>
```

Both attemps above are based on the [answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56239550/xamarin-forms-default-value-for-picker)

But is does not works.

How can I have it so that when the form opens, `English` is set as selected item/index already ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a property for your selected item in your c# then bind it to your picker :

```
private string selectedObj;
public string SelectedObj
{
  get{ return selectedObj;}
  set{ selectedObj= value ; 
     PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedObj"));}
      
}
```

then you can set your value to the selected object any place in your code:

```
SelectedObj = "English";
```

then bind it to picker in xaml:

```
<Picker x:Name="PickerLanguage" Title="" 
        TitleColor="#004973" 
        FontSize="24" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}"
        
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObj}">
</Picker>
```

Comment: This works, but I don't understand the difference with `SelectedItem="English"` Are they not both strings ?

Comment: SelectedItem is of type object, the selected item, which defaults to null.

Comment: Yes, but by doing `SelectedItem = "{Binding SelectedObj}"` don't I also feed it with a string, just as with "English" ?

Comment: But if you read the documentation you will see that the SelectedItem  property is to bind any item you select from the picker , which means every time you change you choice in the picker the SelectedItem  should change, thus you cannt feed it a constant string as your saying.